# PHP write to temporary file and use it as command line argument

Tags: php, shell, command-line, exec, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf files automatically. I take two types of input, url and html. The url type is fine as I just pass the url through the command. However you cannot pass html directly to wkhtmltopdf.

What I have tried to do is:

```
$tmp = tmpfile();
$data = stream_get_meta_data($tmp);
$file = $data['uri'];
fwrite($tmp, $html);

exec(sprintf('wkhtmltopdf %s %s', $file, 'data.pdf'));
```

This doesnt work because the temporary file gets deleted before the command gets executed (or atleast that is what I think happens.) the only work around I can think of is to create my own temp file in the same directory, use that then delete it after generation. Is there any way I can get the tmpfile() method to work?

Comment: It is possible to pass html stream directly to wkhtmltopdf at least in c#. In any case, PHPs `exec()` is synchornous, so the problem is not there. Can you show us the code where you delete the file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once using php-fpm and **systemd** on linux.
The problem was that systemd maps the tmp folder for each process into some private space where it is not accessible by other processes.

You can run

```
locate service | grep service$ | grep php
```

to check where the responsible configuration file is located.
For me this was /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.
In this file under the [Service] section you will find the option

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

As you can read in the comments on the top of that file it seems to be best practice to copy the file to

```
/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service
```

and make your changes there so they will not be overwritten on a package update.
After you have set PrivateTmp=false you have to reload the daemon and probably restart php-fpm with the following commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
service php-fpm restart
```

I hope this resolves your problem.